# Options in the drop down are floating left

Tags: html, css

code snippet

```
<option value="0" data-id="0">gfjhdfgjhgdfhjgdjfgkdffdgdfg </option>

<option value="1" data-id="1">dfgsfghjgsdhfgsgfdsjgshf </option>
```

[existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AnYu.png)
[required... the options should be aligned to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HJUh.png)

Comment: could you elaborate on what exactly you want?

Comment: In my first attachment the dropdown options are overflowing to the right as the string is longer than the dropdown width .... I want that to overflow to left as in the second image.

Answer (score 0):

You have Size- or CSS-definitions that you're omitting, as by default, a select dropdown is at least as wide as it's largest option:

```html
<select>
  <option>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</option>
  <option>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</option>
</select>
```

What you want is furthermore not possible because you can't modify the option dropdown like that, at least not in any browser I know. You can do:

- align all text to the right - this will still leave you with a wider-than-the-select-box dropdown
- set the width of option elements to the width of the select element, which won't render text-align anymore

So, the closest thing I can think of to help you here is this:

```css
select {
  width: 120px;
}
option {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right; /* this doesn't have any effect, it's just added to illustrate that fact */
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</option>
  <option>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But I have the specific width restriction on dropdown and it cant be as wider as the option.

Comment: @praveen: I figure as much, the problem is that unlike block elements, the styleability of form elements is very different from browser to browser and (that's my guess) thought of as better this way, as it means that mobile browsers can decide to show their users a different interface than desktop browsers, for example. That means that your ability to modify this output is very limited, and at least on Gecko (where I tested it), there's no way save for a custom-rendered dropdown menu to do this - and certainly not for mobile browsers, which most of the time completely disregard option styling.